# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onDestroy')" while using observable with NgFor and the Async Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx-store, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to display a list of jobs, the code looks like

```js
 loadJob() {
   let query = { pageNo: this.pageNo, title: this.searchParam.title, location: this.searchParam.location, industry:this.searchParam.industry }
   this.store.dispatch(InitJobComponent({query}));
   this.jobs$ = this.store.pipe(
     select(getJobState)
   );
   
   this.jobs$.subscribe((jobs) => {
     if (jobs && jobs.data && jobs.data.length>0) {
       this.currentJob = jobs.data[0];
       this.checkSaveStatus(this.currentJob);
       this.trustedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.currentJob.file);
     }
   });
 }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(jobs$ | async) as jobs" class="page-wrapper job-list">
  <div class="no-results" *ngIf="jobs.totalCount == 0">
    <h3>No results found.</h3>
  </div>
  <nz-layout *ngIf="jobs.totalCount > 0" class="content">
    <nz-sider class="side-bar-job-list">
      <ul class="jobs" nz-menu nzMode="inline">
        <li nz-menu-item *ngFor="let job of jobs.data; let i=index" (click)="details(job);">
          <!-- whatever the code is to display the list -->
        </li>
      </ul>
      <nz-pagination [nzPageIndex]="pageNo" (nzPageIndexChange)="paginate($event);" [nzTotal]="jobs.totalCount">
      </nz-pagination>
    </nz-sider>
  </nz-layout>
</div>
```

I get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onDestroy')` where I'm trying to use `*ngFor`. I can't figure out why this is happening, please help.

Comment: Try to remove the .angular directory and do npm run

Comment: Where/when is `loadJob()` called? I see it's what assigns a value to `jobs$` so if the pipe tries to run before it has a value that might be the problem

Comment: @Sajeetharan I tried that, didn't work

Comment: @ChrisBarr In ngOnInit function

Comment: We would need the stacktrace to understand what's happening

Comment: Probably only call loadJob in ngOnInit and move  this.store.dispatch(InitJobComponent({query})); to after the this.jobs$ assignment. Also: don't subscribe without unsubscribing (google takeUntil(this.destroy$) for an elegant solution)). You can probably assign  directly  public jobs$ = this.store.pipe(
     select(getJobState)
   );